# Stopping sprites from toppling off platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I am new to Unity and am trying to create a simple 2d platformer. I have applied a box collider to my player sprite and the floor/platform its standing on. Now when I go over the platform, it toppes off of it as expected, but I want it to simple fall off it instead of toppling. How can I do this?
Also I saw a video of Unity Live Training in which he was using a separate circular collider for the player's feet.When I did this ,the sprite started rolling. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "fixed angle" option on Rigidbody2D component, try enabling that